# Converter rótulos em rótulos numéricos

Tags: r

Tenho rótulos armazenados como letras e quero converter para numéricos, por exemplo:

```
a <- c("A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "E", "D", "A", "B")
```

Saída desejada

```
[1] 1 2 1 1 3 5 4 1 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transforme seu vetor `a` em fator e depois converta-o para numérico:

```
as.numeric(factor(a))
[1] 1 2 1 1 3 5 4 1 2
```

É possível até mesmo atribuir valores numéricos diferentes para os níveis de `a`. Por exemplo,

```
as.numeric(factor(a, levels=c("E", "D", "C", "B", "A")))
[1] 5 4 5 5 3 1 2 5 4
```